# Xcode 5 crashes when open xib or storyboard from 4 version

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

May be anybody know how to fix the problem in subj ? I'm using Xcode 5.0.1 and when open project that made in Xcode 4 version I can compile and look at files exempt XIB or storyboard files. When I pick any of these files Xcode has crash.
And I get error report:

```
Process:         Xcode [19762]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.1 (3335.23)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335023000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 84192765
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [196]
Responsible:     Xcode [19762]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration
PlugIn Identifier: com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration
PlugIn Version:    5.0.1 (3746)

Date/Time:       2013-10-28 19:38:38.054 +0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  F14093DD-ED31-C86B-1940-AB938A80AAD1

Sleep/Wake UUID: 07235D2F-2EEE-4BE0-8A4B-172A9119AA67

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000032, 0x000000011959eddc

VM Regions Near 0x11959eddc:
    __LINKEDIT             0000000119410000-0000000119439000 [  164K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Versions/A/GLUT
--> __TEXT                 0000000119439000-000000011968e000 [ 2388K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration
    __DATA                 000000011968e000-0000000119724000 [  600K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A2053

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration   0x000000011959eddc 0x119439000 + 1465820
1   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration   0x00000001194ccaba 0x119439000 + 604858
2   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration   0x00000001194dd3c8 0x119439000 + 672712
3   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration   0x00000001194db2b4 0x119439000 + 664244
4   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000113d4a575 -[IBDocument updateWarningsForMembers:] + 501
5   com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEInterfaceBuilderKit 0x0000000113d4b4fa -[IBDocument validateWarnings:] + 171
6   com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010ee5eb1a -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] + 138
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86a89a9a __NSFirePerformWithOrder + 332
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b77c0a7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b77c017 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b76d7b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 776
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b76d275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b93bf0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b93bb85 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 173
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8b93babc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87db328e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87db28db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87da69cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff87d91803 NSApplicationMain + 940
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9058c5fd start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c76ce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a569f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a56cfb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8c76d662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8b29243d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8b292152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52
```

This is the part of report, cos it very long to publish it here I think

Answer (score 0):

If somebody will face with the same problem:
the main reason was that I updated my Xcode from 4.x version. When I removed Xcode and installed from scratch - problem was disappeared.